# How many System.Timers.Timer instances can I create? How far can I scale?

Tags: .net, timer

I have an application which makes use of [`System.Timers.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) objects to do expirations and email notifications and such.  Currently the system has a couple hundred timers alive at once, but we are going to be expanding the usage of the app and that number might start scaling into the thousands (probably no higher than 10,000).

I can't find any information on scaling up the number of Timers so I assume it is not going to be a problem.  Does anyone know if this is going to be a problem and I should proactively look into changing the way I handle the expirations?

Comment: I have a similar question about Threading.Timer.

Comment: If you're interested, look at the fundamental OS resource that timer class relies upon by using Reflector on system DLLs. Then pose the question to Mark Russinovich
http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/

Comment: @GregC, can you post a link to it so I can check out those answers?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A little late on this, I know, but . . .

`System.Timers.Timer` is a wrapper around `System.Threading.Timer`, which in turn is a .NET wrapper around Windows' [Timer Queues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686796(v=VS.85).aspx).  Timer queue timers are very lightweight--use few system resources.  I've not scaled to thousands of timers, but hundreds of timers works just fine.  From what little I've been able to glean of the implementation, I can't imagine that there would be any trouble with thousands of timers.

There's probably some limit on the number of timers you can have in any particular timer queue.  I don't know what that limit is.  When I investigated these timers a year or so ago, it looked like the .NET Framework creates one timer queue per process (or maybe it was per app domain), and all the timers you create are put into that one queue.

It probably doesn't make sense to duplicate the timer queue functionality by creating your own system that uses a single timer and some type of priority queue mechanism to control what's called next.  That's what the timer queue does for you already.

It seems like you could easily build a test program that creates 10,000 timers.  Set each one to tick one second after the last, and set its period to 10,000 seconds.  Then sit back and watch it tick.  Or have your program keep track of who should tick next and who actually ticks next.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it better to use one timer only? This timer fires e. g. every second or every minute and then you compare DateTime.Now() to the Setpoint DateTime objects of your Schedule Plan.
If Setpoint DateTime object matches DateTime.Now(), fire an event and recalculate the next execution DateTime for your object.

Comment: This strikes me as implementing my own Timer.  I don't remember what I was working on back in 2010 that had me using Timers in this way, but if the abstraction Timers provided was what I wanted, I was obviously looking to avoid implementing my own "Schedule Plan" :)

Answer (score 0):

How about using only one timer? The timer will expired on the first expiration and do the appropriate logic upon expiration. Then reset it's interval to the next expiration? Just maybe another way to handle expiration using only one timer.

Comment: Obviously there are a number of ways to not use lots of timers.  However, I'm wondering if it is worth changing the code.

Answer (score 0):

You should be fine using a lot of them. But like pdiddy says, you really should consider changing your code, if you can. 1 vs 10.000 timers makes a difference. ;-)