# How hardware timers work and affect on software performance?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, assembly, timer, lock-free

I want to use async functions calling. I chose [boost::deadline_timer](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/deadline_timer.html).

For me, hardware-timer is a specific *hardware* (surprisingly), that works independently from CPU and is duty only for monitoring time. At the same time, if I understand correctly, it is also can be used for setting timeout and generating an interrupt when the timeout has been reached. (*timers*)

The primary advantage of that is asynchronous execution. The thread that set a timer can continue working and the callback function will be triggered in the same thread where the timer has been set.

Let me describe as I see it in action.

1. The application contains one or more worker threads. E.g. they process input items and filter them. Let's consider that application has 5 threads and each thread set one timer (5 seconds).
2. Application is working. E.g. current thread is `thread-3`.
3. Timer (`thread-0`) has been expired and generates (probably the wrong term) an interrupt.
4. Thread-context switching (`thread-3` -> `thread-0`);
5. Callback function execution;
6. Timer (`thread-1`) has been expired and generates interruption.

...

*And so on*

**P.S.0.** I understand that this is not only one possible case for multi-threaded application.

Questions:

1. Did I describe the working process rightly?
2. Do I understand correctly that even *current thread* is `thread-0` it also leads to context-switching, since the thread has to stop to execute current code and switch to execute the code from callback fuction?
3. If each thread sets 100k or 500k timers how it will affect on performance?
4. Does hardware have the limit to count of timers?
5. How expensive to update the timeout for a timer?

Comment: Is your interest in an embedded application (with minimal or no OS), or in high-level "application" programming under a full-featured OS like Linux, MacOS, or Windows?

Comment: Why would you want hundreds of thousands of timers per thread?  I think it's typical to have just one, or a handful.  I can easily imagine that allocating hundreds of thousands of separate timers would run you out of something.

Comment: An OS only needs to set a hardware timer for the *next* wake-up.  Not for every pending software-requested timer.  If there's work to keep the CPU busy, it might not need to set a timer and put the CPU to sleep at all, and just check in a timer interrupt when timers have expired.  (Or for higher precision, set a timer in the middle of the upcoming timeslice.)

Comment: Do you need *threads*?  Timers that are interrupt based don't need threads.  The Interrupt Service Routine is a thread.  Basically, you tell the OS which function to execute when the interrupt fires.

Comment: Hardware timers are very platform dependent and lesser OS dependent.  In embedded systems, the hardware timers need to be configured (count up/count down, polling or interrupt, and timing frequency).  Usually these hardware timers can be accessed directly without going through an operating system.  You have to check the data sheets on the hardware timer.  Some hardware timers can manage more than one timer; others are only single timers.  Many System-On-A-Chip and Microcontrollers come with timer(s).  I don't know if this violates your CPU independency.

Comment: Many computers have a main timer.  This timer is used by the OS for task switching, clock/calendar values and maybe other purposes.  Some OSes may chain the timers, for example decrementing each count, and when it elapses, run an associated function.  You'll need to get details on your platform's hardware internals and how the operating system is running.

Comment: As far as execution time expense goes, depends on the Operating System.  If you can avoid the OS, the simple action takes to instructions:  Load a register with a value, then write the value to the hardware timer.  Some Operating Systems may make you go through layer(s) of device drivers, so the expense depends on the operating system.

Comment: Guys, thank you for your comments. I’m interested in the explanation primarily from the operating system side. I need to monitor expired elements in the table, and started to analyze the possible solutions. I understand that I can run “cleaner-thread” by timer, but just wanted to know how it would work with setting async call to “remove-function”.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A hardware timer is, at its core, just a count-up counter and a set of comparators (or a count-down counter that uses the borrow of the MSb as an implicit comparison with 0).
Picture it as a register with a specialized operation *Increment* (or *Decrement*) that is started at every cycle of a clock (the easiest kind of counter with this operation is the [Ripple-counter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counter_(digital)#Asynchronous_(ripple)_counter)).
Each cycle the counter value is also fed to the comparator, previously loaded with a value, and its output will be the input to the CPU (as an interrupt or in a specialized pin).
In the case of a count-down counter, the borrow from the MSb acts as the signal that the value rolled over zero.
These timers have usually more functions, like the ability to stop after they reach the desired value (one-shot), to reset (periodic), to alternate the output state low and high (square wave generator), and other fancy features.

There is no limit on how many timers you can put on a package, of course, albeit simple circuits, they still have a cost in terms of money and space.
Most MCUs have one or two timers, when two, the idea is to use one for generic scheduling and the other for high-priority tasks orthogonal to the OS scheduling.
It's worth noting that having many hardware timers (to be used by the software) is useless unless there are also many CPUs/MCUs since it's easier to use software timers.
On x86 the HPET timer is actually made of at most 32 timers, each with 8 comparators, for a total of 256 timers as seen from the software POV.
The idea was to assign each timer to a specific application.

Applications in an OS don't use the hardware timers directly, because there can possibly be a lot of applications but just one or two timers.
So what the OS does is share the timer.
It does this by programming the timer to generate an interrupt every X units of time and by registering an ISR (Interrupt Service Routine) for such an event.
When a thread/task/program sets up a timer, the OS appends the timer information (periodic vs one-shot, period, ticks left, and callback) to a priority queue using the absolute expiration time as the key (see Peter Cordes comments below) or a list for simple OSes.
Each time the ISR is called the OS will peek at the queue and see if the element on top is expired.

What happens when a software timer is expired is OS-dependent.
Some embedded and small OS may call the timer's callback directly from the context of the ISR.
This is often true if the OS doesn't really have a concept of thread/task (and so of context switch).
Other OSes may append the timer's callback to a list of "to be called soon" functions.
This list will be walked and processed by a specialized task. This is how FreeRTOS does it if the timer task is enabled.
This approach keeps the ISR short and allows programming the hardware timer with a shorter period (in many architectures interrupts are ignored while in an ISR, either by the CPU automatically masking interrupts or by the interrupt controller).
IIRC Windows does something similar, it posts an APC (Async Procedure Call) in the context of the thread that set the software timer just expired. When the thread is scheduled the APC will (as a form of a window's message or not, depending on the specific API used) call the callback. If the thread was waiting on the timer, I think it is just set in the ready state. In any case, it's not scheduled right away but it may get a priority boost.

*Where* the ISR will return is still OS-dependent.
An OS may continue executing the interrupted thread/task until it's scheduled out. In this case, you don't have step 4 immediately after step 3, instead, thread3 will run until its quantum expires.
On the other way around, an OS may signal the end of the ISR to the hardware and then schedule the thread with the callback.
This approach doesn't work if two or more timers expire in the same tick, so a better approach would be to execute a rescheduling, letting the schedule pick up the most appropriate thread.
The scheduling may also take into account other hints given by the thread during the creation of the software timer.
The OS may also just switch context, execute the callback and get back to the ISR context where it continues peeking at the queue.
The OS may even do any of that based on the period of the timer and other hints.

So it works pretty much like you imagined, except that a thread may not be called immediately upon the timer's expiration.

Updating a timer is not expensive.
While all in all the total work is not much, the timer ISR is meant to be called many many times a second.
In fact, I'm not even sure an OS will allow you to create such a huge number (500k) of timers.
[Windows can manage a lot of timers (and their backing threads)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3632063/5801661) but probably not 500k.

The main problem with having a lot of timers is that even if each one performs little work, the total work performed may be too much to keep up with the rate of ticking.
If each X units (e.g. 1ms) of time 100 timers expire, you have X/100 units of time (e.g. 10us) to execute each callback and the callback's code may just be too long to execute in that slice of time.
When this happens the callbacks will be called less often than desired.
More CPU/cores will allow some callback to execute in parallel and would alleviate the pressure.

In general, you need different timers if they run at different rates, otherwise, a single timer that walks a data structure filled with elements of work/data is fine.
Multi-threading can provide concurrency if your tasks are IO-bounded (files, network, input, and so on) or parallelism if you have a multi-processor system.

Comment: Would you really count up and compare, instead of making a down-counter that detects wrapping via a borrow output from the high bit?  You'd still have to store the original value somewhere for periodic counters, but not for one-shot.  Either way it can assert a signal after N clock cycles, but I guess one difference would be whether you can read out cycles already counted vs. cycles left until next interrupt.  So HW timers with that feature might imply one design or the other.

Comment: *Each time the ISR is called the OS walks the list and decrements the ticks left in each software timer.* - I haven't written an OS myself, but I thought it would be more typical for each timer to have a fixed deadline (in wall-clock time or in ticks since some reference point), so the OS is actually just *comparing* whether `now` is later than any of the timers. Or pulling them from a sorted priority queue and acting one ones that have passed, until you find the next future deadline.  Either way, not actually modifying anything in each queued SW event, and hopefully not looping over each.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, it's more likely the OS has a heap structure (a priority queue) and just picks up expired timers. I just wrote the first thing that comes off the top of my head and for many simple scenarios (where implementing a priority queue was too overkill) I used a simple list. Regarding HW timers, I was under the impression they were counting up or bidirectional but I may be wrong, I may remember wrong.

Comment: I don't have practical experience writing drivers for HW timers; there are merits to either approach depending on what SW wants to be able to do in terms of reading or modifying the count after starting.  For purely program-once and get an interrupt later, down-counting is probably slightly simpler HW, since rollover already produces a signal that ripples out the top of a binary subtractor.  I wouldn't be at all surprised if bidirectional is a feature in modern HW timers; most of the total transistors are probably in providing a programming interface for software.

Comment: @PeterCordes FWIW, the LAPIC Timer is a count-down timer. It works as you said. The HPET (High Precision Event Timer) is a count-up but has a set of 8 comparators for each of its 32 timers (so a count-up makes sense in this context). The PIT, the legacy timer on x86, has three count-down counters. So I remembered wrong. Thank for pointing that out!